# JavaScript max ,что в нем не правильно? спасибо

Tags: javascript

```js
function fn3(a, b, c) {
  if (a > b >= c || a > c >= b) {
    return a;
  } else if (b > a >= c || b > c >= a) {
    return b;
  } else if (c > a >= b || c > b >= a) {
    return c;
  }
}
var p = fn3(4, 5, 1);
console.log(p);
```

Comment: Двойное сравнение js не поддерживает. (в том смысле который вы подразумеваете)

Comment: у вас сравнение булева значения с числом идет

Comment: Какой результат вы хотите получить?

Comment: @Cactus вы так пишите как будто C++ поддерживает двойные сравнения

Comment: @Cactus наверное, вы перепутали C++ и Python...

Comment: @PavelMayorov, да, возможно:)

Answer (score 2):

Операторы сравнения возвращают булевское значение, поэтому после того, как сравнились `a > b` результат *true*/*false* будет сравниваться с числом, причем *true* приведется к 1, а *false* - 0.

Для исправления нужно разбить сравнения на пары, например:

```
a > b >= c
```

можно представить как:

```
(a > b) && (b >= c)
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59438/discussion-on-answer-by-grundy-javascript-max------).

Answer (score 2):

Вы разобрали слишком много случаев, но при этом умудрились забыть некоторые. Что выдаст ваша функция при трех одинаковых значениях?

Учитесь упрощать свой код. Зачем вам знать порядок переменных a и b для того чтобы заключить что максимум - это c? Незачем, это лишние проверки.

```
function max3(a, b, c) {
  if (a >= c && a >= b) {
    return a;
  } else if (b >= c && b >= a) {
    return b;
  } else if (c >= b && c >= a) {
    return c;
  }
  return NaN;
}
```

Вот так будет проще и правильнее.

Причину же ошибки вам уже объяснил Grundy.